# Fast way to communicate one short string from C#(UWP) to Java application

Tags: java, c#, uwp, integration, toast

I have a C#(UWP) application which checks Toast Notifications in Windows. When it finds a notification, I want it to pass its Title(Application name which sent Notification) String to my Java application so I can run my java code with input being this string.

What I have tried is after notification is found in C# app, launch a JAR with my java app, but from my tests it takes up to 1500ms. I am looking for something under 10ms.

What would be the best, and fairly easy way to achieve so? I'm not so experienced in C#. I am only using C# because I don't think I can achieve getting Toast notification in Java.

Comment: I can't help but wonder why you have a C# application doing this when you need it in Java.

Comment: If everything is running locally, 1500ms of delay is a lot. Please integrate your question with some code, especially the meaningful networking part of both projects.

Comment: @Llama Like I said, NotificationListener in Windows is available in C#, not in Java. At least the official, Microsoft supported one

Comment: @maxdelia 1500ms is with JAR solution. There is no networking, just launching the Process java.exe with -jar argument

Comment: @SSV without any further information, this sounds like a very bad software architecture. I would develop the entire solution in C#, or change the way in which the data flow between your services. Starting a process (a Java process!) from a C# service every time You receive a notification sounds like the worst solution possible to me, no offense. I would at least made the Java process an always-on deamon, and communicate with it from C# using local rpc calls. Not the best solution, but at least You shouldn't have so much delay.

Comment: @maxdelia I know it is bad, but this is all I have right now, and I wanted to post something which I already tried, not just the question. That is exactly why I am searching for a better way and made this post. I was thinking of using Sockets, but not sure if it will give me <10ms

Comment: @SSV what if You add some HTTP API and make the Java an always-on daemon? Worse than the rpc solution, but way easier to implement!

Comment: @maxdelia Decided to go for ServerSocket approach in my java app(Server), calling it with TcpClient(sendingNetworkStream) on C# side. It's about 120ms since beggining of the logic, till message is received on java side. I don't think REST API would be faster, would it?

Comment: @SSV A REST API call can absolutely be faster, but it depends on a multitude of factors, some of them totally out of your control - if You're ok with the socket solution, there is no reason to going crazy to save some ms IMHO. Just keep in mind that a socket is way more expensive (speaking about resources) compared to HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the JVM running continuously to get low response times.

A good and well documented approach could be turning your java code in to a REST API and call that. Spring boot would be a good option for a stand alone service

The new graalvm compiler may create fast enough programs but I do not have personal experience with this usage.